# prompt loads before anything else

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

hay if anybody understand why is prompt showing up even  before the console printing
i appreciate the help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>promptheadache</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    
        console.log('i should appear first on the console')

        var promptInput = prompt('I\'m am here befor anything else')

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log`s are actually asynchronous in that they are synchronized (as in always in order) but perform an asynchronous call.

`prompt` is a very old API and one of the few that actually blocks the page - so even-though it appears after the `console.log` you see it as soon as it is called.

That said - this is not true for every console nor is it guaranteed - the `console.log` *may* appear before the `prompt` depending on the browser/console implementation.

Comment: hay so the log is called first and waiting for it's q  , meanwhile the prompt getting called and blocking the main thread ?

Comment: @joellhofman basically yes though this isn't generally how things work - `prompt` is a special legacy feature and new APIs don't have this behavior. It's like a piece of old history of the web :) (also note like I said console isn't specified in terms of timing and different browsers/impls may diverge)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the console before prompt you can add setTimeOut-setTimeout() is an asynchronous function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>promptheadache</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    
        console.log('i should appear first on the console')
  setTimeout(() => {var promptInput = prompt('I\'m am here befor anything else')
},5000) 
 
       

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thenks very mach